# Why can't I see my project running in netbeans?

Tags: java, netbeans

I can't get my project to run correctly even though it worked before.

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;
import java.util.Scanner;
       

public class Main {

    static void bar_graph(int un, int deux, int trois, int quatre, int cinque) { //creates method bar_graph to take 5 integers and, for each integer, return that many asterisk
        
        int[] array = {un, deux, trois, quatre, cinque}; //creates array to hold the integers from bar_graph
        String graph = "*"; //creates string equal to *
        
        int counter = 0; //creates integer counter
        
        while(counter < 5){ //beginning of while loop which goes through the five integers in bar_graph and prints out, for each integer, that many asterisk
        String repeated = StringUtils.repeat(graph, array[counter]); //repeats the string graph as many times as the integer at array[counter] and equals it to a string called repeated
        System.out.println(repeated); //string repeated is printed
        counter++; //the counter increases by one
        }
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        System.out.println("Emma Wilson - Programming Project 3 Exercise 4.16");
        
        Scanner graph = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter five integers between 1 and 30: "); //asks user to input five integers between 1 and 30
        
        int first = graph.nextInt(); //creates int first and equals it to first integer the user enters here
        while (first > 30 || first < 1){ //checks that the integer the user entered is between 1 and 30 and asks the user to enter an integer between 1 and 30 over and over
            System.out.println("That is not an integer between 1 and 30. Please enter an integer between 1 and 30: ");
            first = graph.nextInt();
        }
        
        int second = graph.nextInt(); //creates int second and equals it to next integer the user enters here
        while (second > 30 || second < 1){ //checks that the integer the user entered is between 1 and 30 and asks the user to enter an integer between 1 and 30 over and over
            System.out.println("That is not an integer between 1 and 30. Please enter an integer between 1 and 30: ");
            second = graph.nextInt();
        }
        
        int third = graph.nextInt(); //creates int third and equals it to next integer the user enters here
        while (third > 30 || third < 1){ //checks that the integer the user entered is between 1 and 30 and asks the user to enter an integer between 1 and 30 over and over
            System.out.println("That is not an integer between 1 and 30. Please enter an integer between 1 and 30: ");
            third = graph.nextInt();
        }
        
        int fourth = graph.nextInt(); //creates int fourth and equals it to next integer the user enters here
        while (fourth > 30 || fourth < 1){ //checks that the integer the user entered is between 1 and 30 and asks the user to enter an integer between 1 and 30 over and over
            System.out.println("That is not an integer between 1 and 30. Please enter an integer between 1 and 30: ");
            fourth = graph.nextInt();
        }
        
        int fifth = graph.nextInt(); //creates int fifth and equals it to next integer the user enters here
        while (fifth > 30 || fifth < 1){ 
            System.out.println("That is not an integer between 1 and 30. Please enter an integer between 1 and 30: ");
            fifth = graph.nextInt();
        }
        bar_graph(first, second, third, fourth, fifth); //calls method bar_graph
        
        
         
         
         }
}
```

code screenshot 1:
[image]

code screenshot 2:
[image]

code running screenshot 3:
[image]

When I run it, netbeans doesn't show the integers I enter or any output.

Netbeans runs another program I compiled correctly, but not this one.

Comment: Please copy and paste the code into the question, don't use screen shots.  Try to trim down the code to the minimum that reproduces the problem.

Comment: Your code works correctly for me in NetBeans.  You'll have to be more specific about what the problem is.  What is actually happening when you type?

Comment: I almost think netbeans itself isn't working. For example, when I type 5 as an integer when the program is running, it doesn't appear.

Comment: That's what I'm thinking too, you should at least see what you type before you press enter.  Double check the code is working somewhat (use a debugger?), clean the project and recompile.  If that doesn't work you might need to uninstall and reinstall.

Comment: P.S. You might also try compiling and running on the command line, just to double check your Java installation.

Answer (score 0):

you try to run a file but your last file is run instead of the current one.

When opening multiple projects or have more than one file with `main` method and you press "Run" in Netbeans (or pressing F6 to run), this happens and it runs the last file which you have run.

consider it as a key like "run my last run program".

if you want to run another file, just open the file with `main` method, right click every where in your code and press "run file" (or simply press the short-key which is shift + F6).

this way you will tell Netbeans to do not run my last code, run this one instead.

from now on, "run" key in the top of your IDE, runs this file. unless you do the same with another files.